# Detect large and low-resolution (TV) screens

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries, responsive, television

My Web application is meant to be used on desktop computers and also on computers that are connected to TV screens.

I would like to apply different styling in these two different cases, but simple media queries do not work here: TVs resolutions are even smaller than computer monitors, even though the screen is much bigger.

Is there any way to detect such a scenario and apply proper styling ?

Comment: What do you mean it's even smaller? If TV is full hd then it's resolution is the same that res of full hd pc screen, isn't it?

Comment: This is exactly what a media query is used for. Detecting the resolution of the page, and applying styles based on that resolution. The size of the TV vs Monitor has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

there is a CSS media query to check if the client screen is a tv

```
@media tv
```

(instead of `@media screen` for a classic computer screen).

There is also `@media projector`.

Comment: The actual size is not irrelevant, as those devices (TVs and projectors) usually have larger font sizes...

Answer (score -1):

Suggest to take a look at [CSS Units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp), especially the ones beginning with `v`, which are relative to the viewport's size...

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add more context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).